# Drop down menu connected to the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have an assigment to do, there is a database to be made. In the db, there is a 'user' table with info on the users and a 'role' field where there has to be an admin value or a waiter's value. Anyway decided to go with the ENUM way for it, and all is great.
However there has to be a way to manage that table, and in that field, i have to be able to change throught these two values. Using a simple input type=text method it can work, but if an other value is inserted, it changes to blank.

So i decided to go with the drop down list- approach.

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
echo "<form action=edit_profile2.php method = post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text size=10px name=id value=" . $record['id_user'] . "     </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text size=10px name=user value=" . $record['username'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text size=10px name=first value=" . $record['f_name'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text size=10px size=10px name=last value=" . $record['l_name'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=password size=10px name=pass value=" . $record['password'] . " </td>";


echo "<td>" . "<select name=type>";
echo "<option>" . $record['type_user'] .  "</option>";
echo "<option>" . $record['type_user'] .  "</option>";
echo "</select> . </td>";



echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden size=10px name=hidden value=" . $record['id_user'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit size=10px name=update value=update" . " </td>";
echo "</form>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

I tried, instead of adding $record['type_user'], to use the two options (admin,waiter) but that way i couldn't see which is selected before changing the value. So, is there any way for this to make it work?

---

Because it seems that i am not making my self clear on this, here is my update. The following code is the so called problem of mine.

```
echo "<td>" . "<select name=type>";
echo "<option>" . $record['type_user'] .  "</option>";
echo "<option>" . $record['type_user'] .  "</option>";
echo "</select> . </td>";
```

At first, this approach works, because whenever i choose to view a user from the table, the role field is accordingly right. But that code makes a drop-down list with two-same options. As i mentioned above, i tried using instead of $record['type_user'], the actuall two option, for viewing, but i can't manage to get it to show the actuall value of an entry. It works parsially because i can choose throught both of those options. The code for that approach is :

```
echo "<td>" . "<select name=type>";
echo "<option>" . waiter .  "</option>";
echo "<option>" . admin .  "</option>";
echo "</select> . </td>";
```

Comment: A select with two options is much more like a radio button, isn't it?

Comment: write code to validate what is entered...

Comment: @eyp, I'm guessing homework assignment... if that is the case, I would bet the point is to help understand validation using different field types. Sounds like the input type=text is important. Could be wrong though.

Comment: @eyp yes i suppose it would be.

Comment: @MattThompson this is just a piece of the code. i made a validation script for the database changes, but i didn't think it would be usefull for my problem. Thanks for your concerns though.

Comment: I was just implying that if you need to change them using a text box and you have a problem with people entering other values, just validate that it is one of the two choices in the open text field before you accept it. Problem solved. Unless even you don't understand your original question.

Comment: Oh, you mean using plain-text for the changes. Well as a last resort seems wonderfull, but wanted an easy way to change the values plus the downside whenever i put an other value. However for an assignment and for something that i will be using i guess plain text it's ok. Sorry for not understanding what you were saying.

Answer (score 0):

(this is may not be the answer because i am not sure i understand thequestion)

for options you have to set 'value' attribute

```
echo "<option value=".$record['type_user'].">" . $record['type_user'] .  "</option>";
echo "<option value=".$record['type_user'].">" . $record['type_user'] .  "</option>";
```

Then you can get the selected value

Comment: I edited my post. Hope you can see what i mean. Thanks